# Powershell ISE - Variable not interpreted

Tags: powershell, psexec, powershell-ise

I am experimenting with the following  script in Powershell ISE, but this returns an error when executed.

```
$computerName = Read-Host "Enter name of remote computer"
psexec \\"$computerName" cmd
```

The Read-Host part works fine, but when it moves to the psexec line it returns

```
Enter name of remote computer: Computer

psexec : 
At line:2 char:1
+ psexec \\"$computerName" cmd
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

So it seems that the script is not passing the value of $computer. I have tried various " ' combinations to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm rather novice at powershell scripting.

Comment: Try putting the \\ inside the quotes "\\$computerName"

Comment: It fails with 
psexec : 
At line:2 char:1
+ psexec "\\$computerName" cmd

this time

Comment: The part that I don't understand is if I replace the psexec line with say, Write-Host $ComputerName, it works fine, replace $Computername with what was typed during the Read-Host statement.

Comment: I think that the issue is ISE working with psexec. It works fine for me in a regular prompt. Not the first time that the ISE acted oddly.

Comment: Thanks,I think you may be on to something, it works fine when ran from a regular prompt

Comment: Yep, I don't even bother with the ISE anymore. Too much oddness.

Comment: maybe the errors throw you off, but it seems to execute the commands correctly, so I null route the errors

Comment: Why do you need to use `psexec`? `Invoke-Command` is native to Powerhell and does pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated:

right, I tried this, seems to work:

```
$computerName = Read-Host "Enter Name of computer"
$cred = Get-Credential
psexec \\$computerName -u $cred.UserName -p $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password ipconfig 2> $null #hide errors
```

[image: success]

Comment: Execution fails with psexec : 
At line:2 char:1
+ psexec \\("$computerName") cmd

Comment: changed it after trying a few

Comment: Thanks, tried it, however, same issue, it can't connect to the target computer specified in $Computername

Comment: I've turned on my VM and after adding username & password it works - updated answer

Comment: I think it has to be a bug in my environment because, if I supply wrong credentials, it fails with a message saying that connection to the actual computer name has failed (So the variable has been interpreted correctly) However if I supply correct credentials it just hangs. Going to mark your answer as accepted as that seems to be the right way to do it, it just doesn't work on my machine, but works fine on the server here.

Comment: if you use CMD it looks like it hangs, but it's basically a shell that's waiting for input, but no feedback to the powershell host. press `ctrl`+`c` and you got you powershell shell back. do you need an interactive shell?

Comment: Ah that would make sense, how would you get the shell to be interactive ?

Comment: might need to run psexec in a cmd shell locally to fix the interactivity like this:`cmd /C "psexec ..."` - just noticed this is similar to what semtex is suggesting in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on some of the other answers, a method a coworker showed me for more complex psexec strings is as follows:

```
#Use Psexec to Allow all remote connections and Enable PSRemoting
$psexec = "psexec -accepteula \\"+$targetIP+" -u "+$localadmin+" -p "+'"'+$str+'"'+' -h powershell.exe "&{"Set-Item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value * -Force" ; "Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force"}"'
invoke-command -ScriptBlock {cmd /c $args[0]} -Argumentlist $psexec
```

While the above code actually calls psexec on the remote machine then delivers two powershell commands, the problem of authentication causes all sorts of crazy errors in PS.

Hope this helps someone or the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote anything. PowerShell will quote automatically if needed.

```
psexec \\$computerName cmd
```